# How do I parse an external XML file (returned from a POST) with php?

Tags: php, xml, parsing

I have a simple code written (based on some tutorials found around the internet) to parse and display an XML file.  However, I only know how to reference an XML file stored on my server and I would like to be able to use an XML file that is being returned to me from a POST.

Right now my code looks like this:

```
if( ! $xml = simplexml_load_file('test.xml') )
{
    echo 'unable to load XML file';
}
else
{
    foreach( $xml as $event)
    {
        echo 'Title: ';
        echo "<a href=\"$event->url\">$event->title</a><br />";
        echo 'Description: '.$event->info.'<br />';
        echo '<br />';
    }
}
```

Is there some way I can replace the simpleXML_load_file function with one that will allow me to point to the POST URL that returns the XML file?

Answer (score 3):

Use simplexml_load_string instead of loadfile:

```
 simplexml_load_string($_POST['a']);
```

If you get the url to the file in the POST you can propably use the simplexml_load_file function with the url, but if that doesn't work you can use the file_get_contents in combination with the simplexml_load_string:

```
//say $_POST['a'] == 'http://example.com/test.xml';
simplexml_load_file($_POST['a']); // <-- propably works
simplexml_load_string(file_get_contents($_POST['a'])); //<-- defenitly works (propaly what happens internally)
```

also getting contents of external files could be prohibited by running PHP in safe mode.

Answer (score 2):

If you are receiving a file that's been uploaded by the user, you can find it *(the file)* looking at the content of the [`$_FILES`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php) superglobal variable -- and you can read more about files uploads [here](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php) *(for instance, don't forget to call [`move_uploaded_file`](http://php.net/move_uploaded_file) if you don't want the file to be deleted at the end of the request)*.

Then, you can work with this file the same way you already do with not-uploaded files.

If you are receiving an XML string, you can use [`simplexml_load_string`][4] on it.

And if you are only receiving the URL to a remote XML content, you have to :

- download the file to your server
- and, then, parse its content.

This can be done using `simplexml_load_file`, passing the URL as a parameter, if your server is properly configured (i.e. if [`allow_url_fopen`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen) is enabled).

Else, the download will have to be done using [curl](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.curl.php) -- see [`curl_exec`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-exec.php) for a very basic example, and [`curl_setopt`](http://php.net/curl_setopt) for the options you can use (you'll especially want to use `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER`, to get the XML data as a string you can pass to `simplexml_load_string`).

Answer (score 1):

From http://www.developershome.com/wap/wapUpload/wap_upload.asp?page=php4:

> If you do not want to save the
>   uploaded file directly but to process
>   it, the PHP functions
>   file_get_contents() and fread() can
>   help you. The file_get_contents()
>   function returns a string that
>   contains all data of the uploaded
>   file:

```
if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['myFile']['tmp_name']))
  $fileData = file_get_contents($_FILES['myFile']['tmp_name']);
```

That will give you a handle on the raw text within that file.  From there you will need to parse through the XML.  Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Check out [simplexml_load_string](http://php.net/). You can then use [cURL](http://php.net/curl) to do the post and fetch the result. An example:

```
<?php
$xml = simplexml_load_string($string_fetched_with_curl);
?>
```